# "value getOrElse is not a member of String" in template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have the following template code:

**views/Login.scala.html:**

```
@(loginForm: Form[views.Data])

@import mytemplates.loginform

@Main("") {
    email:@loginform(loginForm("email"))
    @*email:@loginForm("email").value.getOrElse("xyz")*@
}
```

**views/mytemplates/loginform.scala.html:**

```
@(emailField: Field)

@emailField.value.getOrElse("xyz")
```

**views/Main.scala.html:**

```
@(page: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
    @content
</html>
```

**views/Data.java:**

```
package views;

import play.data.validation.ValidationError;
import java.util.List;

public class Data {

    public String email = "";

    public Data() { }

    public List<ValidationError> validate() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Compiling the above is successful. But if line `@*email:@loginForm("email").value.getOrElse("xyz")*@` in **Login.scala.html** is uncommented compiling produces an `value getOrElse is not a member of String` error.

Why does this happen? I'd like to exclude the template `mytemplates.loginform` but can't get it to work.

**edit:** Following estmatic's advice I get the following:

**views/Login.scala.html:**

`@loginForm("email").getClass`: class play.data.Form$Field

`@loginForm("email").valueOr("").getClass`: class java.lang.String

**views/mytemplates/loginform.scala.html:**

`@emailField.getClass`: class play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$$anon$1

`@emailField.value.getClass`: class scala.None$

I had to use `valueOr("")` in **Login.scala.html** otherwise a NullPointer execution exception would be produced. Clearly they are all different classes. I haven't used Play framework much and am not sure what this means.

Comment: Can you post the `loginForm` and the `Data` code please?

Comment: **Data.java** added to my question. `loginForm` is the parameter name in the **Login.scala.html** template. `loginform` is the sub-template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it looks like you have a Java project, the framework is going to do some automatic conversions here and there between the Java classes and their Scala equivalent.

Try this out:

```
@loginForm("email").getClass()
@loginForm("email").value.getClass()
```

Make this change on both `Login.scala.html` and `loginform.scala.html` and you'll see that you are dealing with different classes in each scenario.

When you go through the `loginform` template your `field.value` will be wrapped in a `scala.Some` object, which is why `.getOrElse` compiles in that case. When you do it directly in the main view you never leave Java-class-world, so your `field.value` is returned directly as a `String`.

If you are using the latest version of Play then you should be able to use the `Field.valueOr` method instead of `getOrElse`.

```
@loginForm("email").valueOr("xyz")
```